# HoloLens 2 Emulator "[XDE:002] The emulator unable to verify that the virtual machine is running: Exception from HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFFF" error

Tags: visual-studio-2019, hyper-v, hololens, hololens-emulator

I have Windows 10 Education and I have satisfied all the requirements of the Hyper-V. I tried downloading every version of HoloLens 2; however, everytime when I try to open (even Running it as Administrator), I get the same error which is "`[XDE:002] The emulator unable to verify that the virtual machine is running: Exception from HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFFF`"

[image]

I also have Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 and trying to deploy a project from there results the same error. I cannot even open it normally so it is expected I guess.

I tried every possible suggestion in the forums, stackoverflow etc. but none of them worked. Also, there is 0 virtual machines seen in the Hyper-V Manager.

[image]

Can it be related to this? Any ideas?

Comment: What are the specific versions of Windows system and Visual Studio? Regarding Visual Studio 2019, please check the situation mentioned in this document - [Using the HoloLens Emulator - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-hololens-emulator#troubleshooting).

Comment: @ZuochengWang-MSFT Thank you for your reply. My Windows version is Microsoft Windows 10 Education 10.0.19045 (22H2) and Visual Studio 2019 version 16.11.30. I was aware of the problems regarding VS 2019 however I am not even trying to build any project. I cannot even open the Hololens 2 Emulator because of this error. I also tried to build a project but the same error popped out.